# Is it a problem to create a new project instead of updating React Native in Stores?

Tags: react-native

I have an application published on the App Store and Google Play. I want to update React Native to a higher version. "npx react-native upgrade" didn't work. So I will create a new project with "npx react-native init". After installing the packages, I think I will integrate my src folder into the new project. I keep users' data on their devices locally with Realm. If I publish the build of the new project, can users continue to use it without any problems?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is an update to the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Sure they will. Just ensure you sign the apps with the same credentials you used to sign the one in the store then you should be good